# How to add toggleSelectAll functionality checkbox to new header which is generated by header slot

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I tried to customize vuetify data table header with slot.
I disabled default header and made a new header with `v-slot:header`.
The problem is that if I make new header, there is no checkbox which support toggleSelectAll functionality.
The code is below.

```
<template
  v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }"
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
        <v-simple-checkbox
          color="purple"
          v-if="header.value === 'data-table-select'" 
        ></v-simple-checkbox>
        <span v-else>{{header.text}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</template>
```

And here is the Codepen link.
https://codepen.io/em0809/pen/gOrJGjJ

I want to add toggleSelectAll functionality to above simple checkbox.
I tried with `v-slot:header.data-table-select`, but it's not working.

So, Please help me with this if you have experience.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it in 1 step:

- Add `@input="on['toggle-select-all']"` to your `v-simple-checkbox`.

---

```
<template #header="{ props, on }">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.value">
        <v-simple-checkbox
          v-if="header.value === 'data-table-select'"
          v-model="props.everyItem"
          :indeterminate="props.someItems && !props.everyItem"
          color="purple"
          @input="on['toggle-select-all']"
        ></v-simple-checkbox>
        <span v-else>{{ header.text }}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</template>
```

`#header` overwrite `#header.data-table-select` when both of this is using.

Comment: Wow, that's the exact answer what I was looking for.
I wanted to use toogle-select-all method.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in 4 steps:

1. Add `ref` to your v-data-table component
2. Pass additional v-data-table props to header slot
3. Set up your `v-model` (and `indeterminate` prop if needed)
4. Create "selectAll" method that should call `toggleSelectAll` by ref

Example code is shown below:

```
<v-data-table
    ref="table"
    :value="selected"
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
    class="elevation-1"
    hide-default-header
    >
        <template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers, ...props } }">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value">
                        <v-simple-checkbox
                            v-model="props.everyItem"
                            :indeterminate="props.someItems && !props.everyItem"
                            color="purple"
                            v-if="header.value === 'data-table-select'" 
                            @input="selectAll"
                        ></v-simple-checkbox>
                        <span v-else>{{header.text}}</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </template>
</v-data-table>
...
methods: {
    selectAll(val) {
        this.$refs.table.toggleSelectAll(val)
    }
}
...
```

Comment: It worked as expected. I updated Codepen accordingly.

Comment: Hi @ dreamwalker, Your solution also solves the problem, but I think that it would be better to use `@input="on['toggle-select-all']"`

Comment: Yeah, I guess @denisemenov answer should be better because it have no deal with `ref` :)